# If statement to paste values in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am NEW to VBA and need some help.  I am trying to write something that will look in  my sheet named 'ROLLUP' and if cell H5 contains the letters "jan", then I would like to paste the **values** from sheet named 'Project" cells I97:I102 in sheet named "Detail" cells H38:H43.  The following is my code and nothing happens.  Any help?

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub ETC_pop()

month = Worksheets("ROLLUP").Range("H5")

If ws.Name = "Detail" Then
If InStr(month, ("Jan")) > 0 Then
    Worksheets("Detail").Range("H38:H43").Value = Worksheets("Project").Range("I97:I102").Value
  End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Where is `month` declared?  You have `Option Explicit` but no declaration,  Ditto for `ws`

Comment: @TimWilliams I noticed that as well.  Posted an answer to exclude that altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make this one If-statement with two parts

```
Private Sub ETC_pop()

If Sheets("ROLLUP").Range("H5").Text="Jan" Then
    Sheets("Detail").Range("H38:H43").Copy
    Sheets("Project").Range("I97:I102").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If

End Sub
```

Edit:

To account for H5 containing a date, we want to use MONTH() function such as:

```
Private Sub ETC_pop()

If Month(Sheets("ROLLUP").Range("H5"))=1 Then
    Sheets("Detail").Range("H38:H43").Copy
    Sheets("Project").Range("I97:I102").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm.. I tried this and nothing happened.  I should have mentioned that ROLLUP H5 **contains** the letters 'jan'.  It also has a year and some other stuff. But I just want it to see if it has that in it.

Comment: Got'cha; we can fix the code I gave to verify that january is the month of that cell's date, rather than being the only contents of the cell.  Updated now, @mckenzieexcel

Comment: This worked when I changed Sheets to Worksheets and swapped around the copy and paste values (I want to copy *from* 'Project' *into* 'Detail'.  Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

It's better not to use a variable `Month` which is similar to the function, but to use a distinct name, like `myMonth`.

Other notes are inside the code (as comments).

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub ETC_pop()

Dim myMonth As String

myMonth = Worksheets("ROLLUP").Range("H5")

'If ws.Name = "Detail" Then '< -- not needed according to your post
' another option >> use if Case In-sensitive
' If UCASE(myMonth) Like "*JAN*" Then
If myMonth Like "*jan*" Then  
    Worksheets("Detail").Range("H38:H43").Value = Worksheets("Project").Range("I97:I102").Value
End If
'End If

End Sub
```

Comment: @mckenzieexcel try the code in my answer above, let me know if it does what you expected

Comment: what value do you have there ? is it a date ?

Comment: The value in 'ROLLUP' H5 is '04-January' right now... the values in 'Project' I97:I102 are dollar amounts and the cells in 'Detail' H39:H43 are currently blank (and I want them to be the pasted values from 'Project')